# Internal Server Error when visiting the WordPress admin page

Tags: wordpress, server, dashboard, internals

I'm working on this site https://feinfilm.de/ and the front page works ok:

[image: Front page]

but if I go to the admin panel https://feinfilm.de/wp-admin/, I see this:

[image: Internal Server Error]

What might be causing this issue? Thanks

Comment: Like the error message tells you, you might want to check the server error log

Comment: Yeah, check the server logs and add them to your question if they don't contain any sensitive data. "Internal Server Error" can be a number of things, and just the message doesn't help us debug at all.

Comment: We cannot offer any advice or solution with only the error code

Answer (score 0):

It might be because WordPress cannot communicate with your database. If the problem continues please contact your web hosting provider.

Comment: If that was the case then the OP wouldn't be able to see the homepage either, don't you think?